# How to generate xml dtd report for PerfPublisher plugin to visualize on jenkins?

Tags: c++, xml, jenkins, dtd

I have c++ program consisting of two functions one for factorial and one for tabels as follows:

```
void factorial(int a)
{
    int unsigned long long fact = 1;
    for(unsigned i = 1; i<=(unsigned)a; ++i){
    int unsigned long long c = fact *=i;
    cout<<c<<"\n";
    }
  sleep(100);
}
void table(int n){
    for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
    cout<< n << "*"<< i <<"="<<n*i<<"\n";
    }
  sleep(100);
} 
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    factorial(20);
    table(5);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

So,kindly suggest me how would i genearate an xml dtd report of the above c++ program which can be passed to PerfPublisher plugin to visualize on jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said **what** you want to visualise?

While the [PerfPublisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PerfPublisher+Plugin) for Jenkins looks like it can generate a range of fancy graphs, you need to provide some input.

As you kind-of mention, this has to be in the form of XML files which pass the DTD given on the wiki page.

But you haven't said what sort of tests you're running, how you're running them, or what the output is.  This question is far too vague.

Take a look at the "[how to generate your reports](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PerfPublisher+Plugin#PerfPublisherPlugin-Howtogenerateyourreports)" section of the wiki page, and update your question with what you're trying to record and what you've tried, if you're having problems.

Comment: i read wiki but i am not getting that do i need to have test cases inside my c++ program or not and secondly how will i get output in the xml file format

Comment: You seem to be far removed from your original question — what do you want to visualise? Figure that out, then figure out what type of test cases you need to write. If you have no idea how to write test cases for a C++ app, you need to do some searching, some reading, and ask a separate question if you have problems.